# Aligning sentences in a text.txt file using open() function and str.join and split method

Tags: python

I am trying to modify (align sentences in a document) a text in a file using python. I tried the following approach with no success. I don't care if the txt is modified or I can get python to read the aligned sentences in the console. Regardless if I use w or r I get an error.

The document contains the following text: "Hello world. Goodbye world."

```
document = open("text.txt", "w")

def sentence_separator(document):
    sentences = document.split(". ")
    return "\n".join(sentences)

document.close()
```

The desired output or text modification is:

```
Hello world

Goodbye world
```

Any suggestions? Appreciate it.

Comment: What output are you currently getting?

Comment: I get an error message

Comment: Yes.. what error message?

Comment: sentences = document.split(". ")
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Yep, my answer will fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do: `sentences = document.split(". ")`. It's the equivalent of:

`sentences = file(open('text.txt'), 'w').split()`

Which won't work because `.split()` only works for strings.

You need to do: sentences = `document.read().split()`. Don't forget to use `'r+'` flag to `open()` as well.

So overall, you have something like this:

```
f = open("text.txt", "r+")
document = open("text.txt", "r+").read()
sentences = document.split(". ")
f.write("\n".join(sentences))
f.close()
```

So, if input file is:

```
Hello world. Goobye world.
```

Then the output file will become:

```
Hello world
Goodbye world.
```

Comment: OP is also not calling the function that creates their desired output, and they're not writing that output to the file they opened.

Comment: The text just disappeared in the file when doing                     document.read().split(". ")

Comment: Sorry, forgot to change the `open()` flag. I've updated the code.

Comment: Still get the same error and I just noticed we have not included the str.join statement

Comment: It doesn't produce error but it has not aligned the sentences in the document on their separate line

Comment: document.write("\n".join(sentences))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: I don't have `document.write()` in my code, so, please try it again.

Comment: @LiviuIosif cool, if it helped please mark the answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document_in = open("textfile.txt", "r")
document_out = open("textfile_out.txt", "w")
def sentence_separator(document_in, document_out):
        lignes=document_in.readlines()
        for li in lignes:
            l_int=li.split('. ')
            for sub_string in l_int:
                document_out.write(sub_string+'\n')
sentence_separator(document_in,document_out)
document_in.close()
document_out.close()
```